# Usar regex no patsub

Tags: makefile

O make tem a função `patsub` para substituir, ou remover, padrões de texto em uma string. A [documentação](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) só conta com exemplos contendo trechos fixos de texto.

O make conta com alguma forma nativa de aplicar regex a uma string? Algo como:

```
$(patsubst [0-9]+,,"arquivo1 arquivo2 arquivo3")
```

Que substituiria todos os números por nada, retornando:

```
"arquivo arquivo arquivo"
```